# JQuery Mobile Get Json Data According to Datepicker Value

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm on phonegap project. I use jqm framework for it.
I have a web api service to get datas into my mobile application and here i want to use Jquery Mobile Datepicker on this project.

Shortly, i need to get the data according to chosen date.

For example, here; http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Is there any usage like make the input auto post back, and let the program gets data according to textbox value ?

I also read here ; http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Is there any example for me to inspect ? I googled but couldnt see the example like my thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/r2CuF/

I have removed JSON from my example because it is a private data.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" /> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>          
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>                
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div data-role="page" id="info">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Info
                </h3>
                <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            </div>
        </div>         
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){       
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
        onSelect: function(date, instance) {
            selectedDate.date = date;
            $.mobile.changePage( "#info", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: false,
                changeHash: false
            });            
        } 
    });
});

$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#info', function(){    
    var json = $.parseJSON(dateHandler.json);
    $.each(json.Dates, function(id,date) {
        console.log(date.Date + '-' + selectedDate.date);
        var patt = new RegExp(selectedDate.date); 
        if(patt.test(date.Date)) {
            $('#info [data-role="content"]').append(JSON.stringify(date.Date)); 
        }
    });
});    

var selectedDate = {
    date : null
}

var dateHandler = {
    json : ''
}
```